# How to insert simulink model into another simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

How do i insert this simulink model into second screen shot?
This is the Rayleigh channel [image]
and I want to insert it into the simulink model on the place where red arrow shows. 
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please insert the images into the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have your first image in a separate file to the second image then use the [Model Referencing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model.html) block.

If you want them both in the same file then you can either copy and paste the blocks themselves, or group them into a [Subsystem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/subsystem.html) and copy that across.